# Group by is not showing all the rows

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am working in WordPress and below is my select query. I have used leftjoin and group by. But only one row is returned if I have duplicate entries in my articles.username coloumn. So I want all the rows to be returned with group by and duplicates should be allowed in username field.
PHP Code

```
$sqll = "SELECT articles.aid, articles.username, articles.competition, articles.path, articles.category, articles.title, Sum(zvotes.zvotes) AS votessum FROM articles LEFT JOIN zvotes on articles.aid=zvotes.aid GROUP BY articles.competition HAVING articles.category = '$cat' && articles.competition = '$comp' ORDER BY votessum";

    $results = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare($sqll)) or die(mysql_error());
```

Snapshot of articles table
[image: This is the articles table]

Snapshot of votes table (currently no data in it)
[image: Votes table]

Below is my full code

```
echo '<form action="" method="post">';
echo '<select name="category" id="category" style="width:250px; background-color:lightgrey;">';
echo    '<option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected" ">Select category</option>';
echo   '<option value="My Testimony">My Testimony</option>';
echo    '<option value="Love & Relationships">Love & Relationships</option>';
echo    '<option value="Miscellaneous">Miscellaneous</option>';
echo '</select>'; 
echo    '<input type="submit" name="a" value="Search"  style="margin-left:15px; margin-bottom:15px;">';
echo '</form>';


//show after drop down value is selected
if(isset($_POST['a'])){
//echo "zeeshanaslamdurrani". "<br>";

echo do_shortcode('[ujicountdown id="Photos Contest" expire="2015/04/30 00:00" hide="true" url="" subscr="sdf" recurring="" rectype="second" repeats=""]');
      global $wpdb;
//get current competition value
$cat =$_POST['category'];
        $comp = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT competition FROM competition ORDER BY cid DESC LIMIT 1");
//echo $comp;
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM articles WHERE category='$cat'";

      $comp = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT competition FROM competition ORDER BY cid DESC LIMIT 1");
            echo "current competition is ". $comp;

//test query
      $sqll = "SELECT articles.aid, articles.username, articles.competition, articles.path, articles.category, articles.title, Sum(zvotes.zvotes) AS votessum FROM articles LEFT JOIN zvotes on articles.aid=zvotes.aid GROUP BY articles.competition HAVING articles.category = '$cat' && articles.competition = '$comp' ORDER BY votessum";

$results = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare($sqll)) or die(mysql_error());

foreach( $results as $result ) {
echo '<form action="" method="post">';
echo "<input name='category' type='hidden' value='$result->category'>";
echo $result->title.'<br>';
echo "<img src='$result->path' width='150' height='150' >" . '<br><br>';
echo $result->body.'<br>';
echo "<input name='comp' type='hidden' value='$result->competition'>";
echo $result->username.'<br>';

echo $result->votessum.'<br>';
echo "<input style='margin-bottom:30px;' value='vote' name='submit' type='submit'/></form>";    

}//end of foreach




}//end of isset
```

I have a drop down on the top of the page and a search button as shown below on pressing search the results are shown but if I add duplicate values in username field of articles table I get only 1 row in result.
My page[image]

Comment: Please edit your query and show sample data and desired results.

Comment: Note that wordpress (and php) have almost no bearing on the question or the answer, and formatting the question has "here is my wordpress/php code" actually makes it harder for those best able to help you to find the info. Luckily for you it wasn't a hindrance this time - worth keeping in mind though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show each user, then I think you should be aggregating by the user.  In fact, you should be aggregating by every column in the `SELECT` that is not an argument to an aggregation function.

This may do what you want:

```
SELECT a.aid, a.username, a.competition, a.path, a.category, a.title,   
       Sum(z.zvotes) AS votessum
FROM articles a LEFT JOIN
     zvotes z
     on a.aid = z.aid
WHERE a.category = '$cat' AND a.competition = '$comp'
GROUP BY a.aid, a.username, a.competition, a.path, a.category, a.title
ORDER BY votessum";
```